# Access gmail inbox messages using Blackberry API

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Blackberry has the ability to receive gmail messages and they show up in the list of incoming messages along with other email accounts, text messages, etc..  Im trying to access these gmail messages programatically  using the Store class but these messages are nowhere to be found.

Below shows basically what I'm trying to do.  Why don't gmail messages show up in the inbox folders, but yet they do show up in the mail application?

```
Store store = null;
Folder[] folderList = null;
Messages[] messageList = null;
int messageCount = 0;

try{
    store = Session.waitForDefaultSession().getStore();
    folderList = store.list(Folder.Inbox);

        for(int i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++){

            messageCount += folderList[i].getMessages().length;
        }
    }
catch(Exception e{


}
```

Comment: Blackberry? Didn't that used to be a smart phone? :P

Comment: Hahah, yea... I'm not going to disagree with you.